# merging element of two different arrays into dictionary in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

i have two arrays like these

```
var arr1 = ["han", "Ji", "Kidda", "Ho", "Tusi"]
var arr2 = ["hello", "Ji"]
```

i want to create a new dictionary that have first element of first array and first element of second array and so on. when the third element of first array comes it should again get the first element of second array.

for example:-

```
dict = ["han" : "hello", "Ji" : "Ji", "Kidda" : hello, "Ho" : "Ji", "Tusi" : "hello"]
```

Comment: Dictionary keyed by what? Show exactly the desired output for the given input.

Comment: i edited the question sir. please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second array has 2 items you can do

```
var dict = [String: String]()
for (index, item) in arr1.enumerated() {
    dict[item] = arr2[index % 2]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for (using `arr1` as the `keys` and `arr2` as the `values` repeating them as necessary):

```
var arr1 = ["han", "Ji", "Kidda", "Ho", "Tusi"]
var arr2 = ["hello", "Ji"]

let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: zip(arr1, arr1.indices.map { arr2[$0 % arr2.count] }))

print(dict)
```

> ```
> ["Kidda": "hello", "Ji": "Ji", "han": "hello", "Ho": "Ji", "Tusi": "hello"]
> ```

**Note:**

Dictionaries have no specified ordering.  Only the key/value pairings matter.  This matches the example in your question.

**Explanation:**

`zip` is used to create a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples from two sequences that will become the key/value pairs for the new `Dictionary`.  The keys come from `arr1`.  `map` is used to generate the sequence of values from `arr2` repeating them as many times as necessary to match the count of `arr1`.  This sequence of `(key, value)` tuples is passed to `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` to turn that sequence into the desired `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var dict = ["arr1" : "hello", "arr2" : "Ji"]
```

then for third you can append by

```
dict[3] = ["arr3" : String(arr3.first())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var arr1 = ["han", "Ji", "Kidda", "Ho", "Tusi"]
var arr2 = ["hello", "Ji"]

var dict : [String : String] = [:]

var arr2Index = 0

for index in 0..<arr1.count {
    let arr1Value = arr1[index]

    if arr2Index == arr2.count {
        arr2Index = 0
    }

    let arr2Value = arr2[arr2Index]

    dict[arr1Value] = arr2Value

    arr2Index += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way:

```
let arr1 = ["han", "Ji", "Kidda", "Ho", "Tusi"]
let arr2 = ["hello", "Ji"]
let arr3 = Array(repeating: arr2, count: arr1.count).joined()
let d = zip(arr1,arr3).reduce(into: [String:String]()) { $0[$1.0] = $1.1 }
```